# How to reference the code_click to a specific worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

How I can refer to Worksheets("Customers") without activating the worksheet in the below code?

Application.ScreenUpdating does not do the job, as there is still annoying flickering.

The code is working fine when I uncomment 'Worksheets("Customers").Activate

I want to perform all steps when Worksheets("Dashboard") is open.

I have tried "With ... End With" but no luck., also referencing Worksheets("Customers").Cells..... etc are not working. Its like code skipping through the code and goes straight to
"

```
 If SearchRow = 2 Then
    MsgBox "Customer Not Found", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
"
```

I also have another code similar issue, that for some reason referencing not working as it should.

Just want to mention that I am using this code with the userforms and click buttons.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
Private Sub srCus_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RowNum As Long
Dim SearchRow As Long

RowNum = 2
SearchRow = 2

Worksheets("SearchCus").Range("A2:I100").ClearContents

'Worksheets("Customers").Activate

Do Until Worksheets("Customers").Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = ""
    If InStr(1, Cells(RowNum, 3).Value, CusDB.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 1).Value = Cells(RowNum, 1).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 2).Value = Cells(RowNum, 2).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 3).Value = Cells(RowNum, 3).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 4).Value = Cells(RowNum, 4).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 5).Value = Cells(RowNum, 5).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 6).Value = Cells(RowNum, 6).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 7).Value = Cells(RowNum, 7).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 8).Value = Cells(RowNum, 8).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 9).Value = Cells(RowNum, 9).Value
        SearchRow = SearchRow + 1
    End If
    RowNum = RowNum + 1
Loop

If SearchRow = 2 Then
    MsgBox "Customer Not Found", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
ResultsDB.RowSource = "SearchResults"

'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add a sheet reference to all these `Cells(RowNum, 1)`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have tried this already, it is skipping through the code and it goes to MsgBox "Customer Not Found" .

Comment: Is it skipping the Do loop? If so, A2 is empty.

Comment: This is the problem, looks like it is not referencing to "Customers", the Column A in "Customers" contains a database of all customers and it is always full of rows. And I want to perform the code with a click of a button on "Dashboard" sheet.

Comment: Step through your code using F8 to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks SJR F8 pointed out to InStr. So simple but so hard at the same time :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SJR, You were right with reference to all these Cells(RowNum, 1), I was always skipping one with InStr line. Thanks for the help and all suggestions. Reviewed code below.

```
Private Sub srCus_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RowNum As Long
Dim SearchRow As Long

RowNum = 2
SearchRow = 2

Worksheets("SearchCus").Range("A2:I100").ClearContents

'Worksheets("Customers").Activate

Do Until Worksheets("Customers").Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = ""
    If InStr(1, Worksheets("Customers").Cells(RowNum, 3).Value, CusDB.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 1).Value = Worksheets("Customers").Cells(RowNum, 1).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 2).Value = Worksheets("Customers").Cells(RowNum, 2).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 3).Value = Worksheets("Customers").Cells(RowNum, 3).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 4).Value = Worksheets("Customers").Cells(RowNum, 4).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 5).Value = Worksheets("Customers").Cells(RowNum, 5).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 6).Value = Worksheets("Customers").Cells(RowNum, 6).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 7).Value = Worksheets("Customers").Cells(RowNum, 7).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 8).Value = Worksheets("Customers").Cells(RowNum, 8).Value
        Worksheets("SearchCus").Cells(SearchRow, 9).Value = Worksheets("Customers").Cells(RowNum, 9).Value
        SearchRow = SearchRow + 1
    End If
    RowNum = RowNum + 1
Loop

If SearchRow = 2 Then
    MsgBox "Customer Not Found", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
ResultsDB.RowSource = "SearchResults"

'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```